# Why does Fetch API Send the first PUT request as OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a `cors` PUT request using the vanilla [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

When I click my button to send the PUT request, the method on the first request is `OPTIONS`. It is only when I click the button again, then the method on the request changes to `PUT`. Why?

I understand this is part of the CORS preflight, but is there a way to trigger the preflight manually so the OPTIONS response can be cached?

Could this behavior be indicative of a failing promise somewhere?

Comment: Have you read the specification?

Comment: Yes, I've read the spec. I'm wondering how this is handled -- do I need to check the already sent request to see if it's an OPTIONS request then send it again?

Comment: Is the specification not clear?

Comment: No, it's not. Does the preflight fetch happen manually or automatically?

Comment: Can you include the `javascript` that you are trying at Question? You could perform the request manually, if, from what can gather, the preflight request is occurring automatically. `fetch("url", {method:"OPTIONS"})
.then(response => response.headers)
.then(_headers => Array.from(_headers.entries(), h => console.log(h))).catch(err => console.error(err))`, else, from reading of specification, a network error would occur. If from your interpretation the specification is not clear, would suggest searching for a similar issue, or filing an issue at https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues

Comment: You are completely correct -- the REAL issue was bad UI in the Google Chrome network explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), section [4.7. CORS-preflight fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch).

> ***Note***: This is effectively the user agent implementation of the check to see if the [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol) is understood. The so-called [CORS-preflight request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-request). If successful it populates the [CORS-preflight cache](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-cache) to minimize the number of these fetches.

at steps 1 through 7; also [4.8. CORS-preflight cache](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-cache).