# Why javascript fetch only making OPTIONS and not making further calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, http-options-method

I am making AJAX request with javascript fetch, but it is only making OPTIONS call and not making further call. Weirdest thing is that the response header is just fine and $.ajax is working as expected.

Here is the response header on OPTIONS call.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 30000000
Set-Cookie: XXXXXXXXXXXX
Date: Wed, 16 Aug 2017 00:57:48 GMT
```

And here is fetch header set.

```
mode: 'cors',
credentials: 'include',
headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer Token'
}
```

Comment: because it's a CORS request preflight check - see [documentation on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - odd that you can't see the GET/POST (whichever you are actually doing) request though

Comment: You sure it's not making any more calls? Because you state it's working--so it must be making the other call.

Comment: I don't see it on network tab... @DaveNewton

Comment: @JaromandaX I already took look at CORS doc again, but it doesn't help.

Comment: You can chain the actual request to the response of `OPTIONS` request

Comment: how do I do it @guest271314 ?

Comment: See [Why does Fetch API Send the first PUT request as OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42311018/) `fetch("url", {method:"OPTIONS"}) .then(response => response.headers) .then(_headers => (Array.from(_headers.entries(), h => console.log(h)), // check expected headers here fetch(url))).catch(err => console.error(err)).then(response => response.text()).then(text => //do stuff)`

Comment: thanks @guest271314 I think it gets the response. Looks like it's chrome issue that it is not showing on network tab.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem today and I found out that my POST call was actually happening, it just didn't show up under the Chrome XHR network filter. By changing the filter to 'all', I was able to see the request.

Comment: Thanks man, I wasted 30 minutes going insane with this and it's always the simplest thing.

Comment: Thanks @Borre, You save my time :)