# Unable to get JSON using Fetch API, but can using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, fetch-api

I'm integrating a React project into a Grails/Angular system, and I'm trying to query Grails using the Fetch API from React.

With the application running and the Chrome developer tools console open, the following works as expected:

```
$.get('/project/controller/get', function(data, status) {
  console.log(data); 
});
```

It displays a bunch of JSON, like so:
[image]

The following does not work as expected:

```
fetch('/project/controller/get', {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

It gives a syntax error because it is trying to parse an HTML document as JSON.

In the developer tools network tab, I see that when I make the JQuery request, there is only a single GET request, and the server response is the JSON I desire.

When I make the request using the Fetch API, two requests appear:

- One to /project/controller/get, which just responds with status code 302, and no JSON
- Another to /project which responds with status code 200, and the HTML for the front page of the application. This is what the Fetch API receives and tries to parse as JSON.

I can verify that the Grails controller method generates the data as expected before the render as JSON statement is executed.

Same thing happens using Axios.

JQuery request details:

General

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/project/controller/get

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response headers

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 02:41:59 GMT

Request headers

GET /project/controller/get HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8080

Connection: keep-alive

Accept: */*

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36

Referer: http://localhost:8080/project/settings/

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2

Cookie: JSESSIONID=52F86C47C43F558E05C2F6DB5E9E7CE2

Is there any way I can get this to work? Thanks.

---

I just noticed entering http://localhost:8080/project/controller/get in the browser automatically redirects me to http://localhost:8080/project for some reason. Might be the server doing something weird, but it's strange that the JQuery request works...

Comment: `Content-Type` header is used to specify the data type of your request body. Since you're making a get request, you don't need that. Try removing it.

Comment: _"It gives a syntax error because it is trying to parse an HTML document as JSON."_ Can you create a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the code perhaps using [`jQuery.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) to set default values for Ajax requests? Regardless, for your fetch request, have you tried using `headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }` or some variation of that? (That is, setting an Accept header for the GET request, rather then setting the Content-Type for it — which as noted in an earlier comment is not going to have any effect.) When you look in your browser devtools at the request the jQuery `$.get` call is sending, what Accept header is it sending?

Comment: Also your jquery example is querying a different url than your fetch example:

Comment: Changing the headers to `headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json'}` doesn't affect it. It still gets back HTML.

Comment: _"It still gets back HTML"_ What is the response full HTML?

Comment: _"It displays a bunch of JSON"_ How is that possible where `Content-Type` of response at `$.get()` is `"text/html;charset=utf-8"`?

Comment: The response is the HTML you get when you visit the main webpage at the root url: /project. Somehow the fetch request results in another request to get the home page of the website

Comment: _"The response is the HTML"_ Why is `JSON` mentioned at original Question at _"It displays a bunch of JSON"_ if you are expecting response to be HTML? Why do you call `Response.json()`?

Comment: I'm actually expecting the response to be the JSON you get when you query the /project/controller/get URL. The issue is that I'm getting the HTML that we expect to get when querying the /project URL.

Comment: _"I'm actually expecting the response to be the JSON you get when you query the /project/controller/get URL. The issue is that I'm getting the HTML that we expect to get when querying the /project URL"_ Not certain what you mean? Are you referencing two different URLs? Can you include expected `JSON` response at Question? What is the purpose of `credentials:"include"` property at `fetch()` call?

Comment: If you enter the URL http://localhost:8080/project in your browser, you get HTML which renders a page in your browser. If you enter http://localhost:8080/project/controller/get in your browser, you get a JSON object, which is the information I'm trying to get using Fetch API. `credentials: "include"` sets the authentication cookie

Comment: Can you include the `JSON` that you are requesting at Question? The issue appears to be at server, if HTML is served as response where you are expecting `JSON`.

Comment: `{"notAuthenticated":true}[{"id":123}]` is not valid `JSON`

Answer (score 2):

302 is a redirect so your fetch request is redirect to another page, maybe a login page (?)

I see in your fetch request you are using `credentials:'include'` and maybe this are including a Authorization header or something similar and your controller are rejecting the request.

With chrome developper console you can inspect the request if you mark "preserve log" at network tab

Answer (score 1):

> It gives a syntax error because it is trying to parse an HTML document
>   as JSON.

If the response is HTML use `Response.text()`

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to get it to return JSON, given that the same URL *does* return JSON when queried via a jQuery `$.get()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn _"given that the same URL does return JSON when queried via a jQuery `$.get()`"_  How do we know for certain that `"application/json"` is served? Why would OP mention an HTML document if the response is valid `JSON`?

Comment: The question explicitly says that requests to the same URL produce different responses depending on whether they use `$.get()` or `fetch()`. They also see different behaviour in the console network tab. That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @nnnnnn No that is not the point of the Question. OP explicitly mentions an HTML `document` at text of Question. How is an HTML document related to `JSON`? OP needs to reproduce valid `JSON` throwing an error at `Response.json()` call.

Comment: They're not related. Because, again, that is the very problem they're trying to solve. Read it again, noting the description of what happens with `$.get()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn The description is irrelevant without the ability to reproduce what is described. That is one of the fundamental principles of the scientific method. Can you explain why there is an error at `Response.json()` call where valid `JSON` is the response? Are you suggesting that `Response.json()` has a bug? One issue could be the headers passed. Where does OP authenticate? OP could be receiving an error message from server that reaches `.then()`. `.catch()` would only be reached if a network error occured.

Comment: No, there *isn't* a valid JSON response when `fetch()` is used. The question spells that out very clearly, and that's what they want to fix. But there *is* a valid JSON response when `$.get()` is used. They use the same URL in both cases, but the behaviour is different. I don't know how to make that any clearer. (And yes, the headers could be the problem. The `fetch()` seems to be doing some sort of preflight request - the question explains how it results in two requests showing in the network tab.)

Comment: @nnnnnn The requests are not the same. Where does OP pass headers at `$.get()` call? You can only speculate that the requests and responses are the same. OP has not reproduced the issue.

Comment: I didn't say the *requests* were the same, I said the *URLs* were the same. The question itself makes it clear that the requests are not the same because `fetch()` actually makes two requests. But they're asking why that is and how to fix it. Maybe they need to provide more info about the headers, etc., but either way this answer doesn't cover what they're asking about.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is possibly an `OPTIONS` request, evidently to authenticate. A second `.then()` could be chained to an `OPTIONS` request to determine if CORS or other headers are in response from server, see [Why does Fetch API Send the first PUT request as OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42311018/). Again, the code should be reproducible at either jsfiddle or plnkr; potentially at stacksnippets, with some adjustments. The URLs may or may not be the same though the headers are not the same.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good catch by Brandon https://stackoverflow.com/users/674326/brandon at `$.get()` `'project/controller/get'`, at `fetch()` `'/project/controller/get'`

Comment: Ah yes. Subtle, but important.

Comment: @nnnnnn Note the updated Question, `$.get()` response is `"text/html"`